# Error installing Geoviews (cartopy) on Windows

Tags: installation, cartopy, geoviews

after started using and learning Holoviews-Panel-HvPlot, I'd like to learn Geoviews. Unfortunatly, problems started when I tried to install it. Down below the message. Just some more details:

- I'm a Windows 10 user
- My Python version is 3.10.4
- I've just pip3.10 installed last versions of both Geos and Proj (as in the error message)
- I've read that Geoviews requires some out of python extensions that I can't get with 'pip' but I have no idea what we're talking about
- Someone suggested to use a virtual environment for Anaconda but I don't use it. Moreover,I'd prefer having it installed in my general environment as I hope to use it often in the future.

Anyway, here the Error Message:

```
   Collecting cartopy>=0.18.0
      Using cached Cartopy-0.20.3.tar.gz (10.8 MB)
      Installing build dependencies ... done
      Getting requirements to build wheel ... error
      error: subprocess-exited-with-error
      
      × Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
      │ exit code: 1
      ╰─> [3 lines of output]
          <string>:117: UserWarning: Unable to determine GEOS version. Ensure you have 3.7.2 or later installed, or installation may fail.
          <string>:166: UserWarning: Unable to determine Proj version. Ensure you have 8.0.0 or later installed, or installation may fail.
          Proj version 0.0.0 is installed, but cartopy requires at least version 8.0.0.
          [end of output]
    
      note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
    error: subprocess-exited-with-error
    
    × Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
    │ exit code: 1
    ╰─> See above for output.
    
    note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using pip install to install Cartopy but missing Proj version at least 4.9.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53697814/using-pip-install-to-install-cartopy-but-missing-proj-version-at-least-4-9-0)

Comment: definitely don't install anaconda, but I'd highly recommend using [`miniforge`](https://github.com/conda-forge/miniforge#miniforge), a variant of miniconda. If you're starting to work with geospatial libraries you're going to start running into this problem *a lot*. These libraries rely on compiled binaries written in a number of different languages. Conda manages these dependencies well, pip completely fails. If you're hoping for a "one env to rule them all", I'd strongly recommend using miniforge and creating an environment (not in your base environment) which has all the libs you need.

Comment: ... I fully agree with @MichaelDelgado... however I'd recommend using  [mambaforge](https://github.com/conda-forge/miniforge#mambaforge) right away since it will provide a remarkable speedup compared to conda (especially when the dependencies get a bit complicated)... you then just replace `conda install` with `mamba install` and solving dependencies will be 100 times faster than before